# Barebones "work-only" Station

Tags: command-line, productivity

I want to buy/build/configure a computer to be used only for programming work. In order to avoid distractions, I want limit myself to use no more than command-line terminals. I don't want to have any GUIs or graphical browsers etc.

Is there a way for me to accomplish this feat?

Comment: I would use a Linux to achieve this.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know of a linux machine that doesn't use anything beyond a command line terminal as its interface?

Comment: If I did suggest a specific distribution then this question wouldn't be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with any Linux distribution and not install the GUI. Slackware is a popular option for this, as is installing Debian without the GUI. If you decide to go with an established distro, just research them out to find which one meets your specific needs.

Another option would be building your own Linux. This will take some time and patience, but it's ultimately rewarding. Check out Linux from Scratch for more info on this: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/